# Module Entry Page for Mobile App on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am intended to create a basic phone application which stores minimum of 5 modules entered by the student.

The snapshot shows my design which consists of the module name, timing, date, etc.. I wonder what could be the easiest way to store those data and then enables me to delete and edit later?

[image: Snapshot]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If locally appsettings or isolatedstorage. Online mobileservice with azure if you are used to c#.

Comment: Local one please. It could be very basic like class and list. So I can add modules, delete, edit.